# Unit testing IHttpActionResult with OkNegotiatedContentResult having anonymous types

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, mstest

I am using MS Test for Unit Testing my Web API Controller.

Below is my Web API Controller method with the return type:

```
public IHttpActionResult MethodName(){ //Code logic 
    return Ok(new { Data = result, Total = (result.Count() > 0 ? result.First().TotalCount : 0) });
}
```

In above code snippet:

1. Data is of Type IEnumerable<ViewModelName'>
2. Total Count is of Type Int

Now for testing above API method return type below is what I have tried :

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethodName(){
var result = controller.MethodName();
//Below line is having issue and thus the contentResult is null 
var contentResult = result as OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<ViewModelName>>;
}
```

Adding Int to OkNegotiatedContentResult throws error as it only excepts single parameter <T'>

Below is the actual return type from the API:

{System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult<<>f__AnonymousType0<System.Collections.Generic.List<ViewModel'>, int>>}

How should I convert result so that I can use its content into Assert ?

Thank you in advance.
Code sample is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the answer I gave here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42718643/5233410

Comment: @NKosi It seems good but I do not have async Task<IHttpActionResult>

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're running into is that your `OkNegotiatedContentResult<T>` has an anonymous type for `T`. The compiler generates an anonymous type for you when you create an adhoc type as you're doing with `new { Date = .., Total =.. }`. By design, anonymous types have a name that you can never use in C# code but that's only valid in the compiled JIT code.

This is why converting your result to `OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<ViewModelName>>` won't work because `T` is not `List<ViewModelName>` but it's of `anonymoustype<System.Collections.Generic.List<ViewModel'>, int>>`.

In my opion, the best option is not use an anonymus type but create an actual class that has the two properties you're looking for and use that type both in your controller and in your test.

```
public class MyData
{
  public List<ViewModel> Data { get; set; }
  public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't want to change the code you could use reflection or the dynamic keyword like this:

```
dynamic contentResult = (dynamic)result.Content;
var data = contentResult.Data
```

Comment: I understood your answer. Still isn't there any way to test it without changing its implementation @WouterdeKort

Comment: @Jimesh I've updated the answer with another solution to use dynamic

Comment: There is a build error stating: "IHttpActionResult does not contain a definition for Content and no exception method content accepting a first argument of type IHttpActionResult could be found"

FYI: I have already added Microsoft.CSharp.dll for dynamic

Comment: @Jimesh change the return type of your action method to be `OkNegotiatedContentResult`

Comment: Not an alternative as changing return type from IHttpActionResult to OkNegotiatedContentResult would require to Pass <T> which ultimately is the first solution "Create an actual class instead of using anonymous types".

Comment: @Jimesh What if you change `(dynamic)result.Content;` to `((dynamic)result).Content;`?

Comment: There is a runtime exception: 

An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Content'

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, which might seem a bit cumbersome at first sight.

So, first make sure that we have received an `OkNegotiatedContentResult`

```
//Act
var actionResult = controller.MethodName();

//Assert - OkNegotiated result
var resultType = actionResult.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition();
Assert.AreEqual(resultType.GetGenericTypeDefinition(), typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<>));
```

Then make sure that anonymous type defines the `Data` property

**DISCLAIMER**: The below code fails in runtime to retrieve `Content`

```
//Assert - Anonymous type
dynamic content = ((dynamic)actionResult).Content;
Assert.IsTrue(content.GetType().GetProperty("Data") != null);
```

And finally make sure that the `Data` property is a collection

```
//Assert - Data property 
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(content.Data, typeof(IEnumerable<ViewModelName>));
var data = (IEnumerable<ViewModelName>)content.Data;
```

Comment: Thank you for the efforts.
The main issue is "var content = result.Content".
Error: "IHttpActionResult does not contain a definition for Content and not extension method Content excepting a first argument of type IHttpActionResult could be found"

Comment: Also before that while Assert.IsInstanceOfType I am getting:
"Assert.IsInstanceOfType failed.  Expected type:<System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult`1[System.Object]>. Actual type:<System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ViewModel],System.Int32]]>."

Comment: @Jimesh Please bear in mind that I've used `actionResult` variable to store the result of `controller.MethodName` call. Then I've used `result` after casting it to `OkNegotiatedContentResult`. In your test code your `result` is truly an `IHttpActinResult`, whereas in my version it should be a `OkNegotiatedContentResult`, which does have a `Content` property.

Comment: I have the same code snippet as yours.

Getting: An exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssertFailedException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Assert.IsInstanceOfType failed.  Expected type:<System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult`1[System.Object]>. Actual type:<System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ViewModel],System.Int32]]>.

Comment: @Jimesh That's just weird. Let's skip that line and could you please try this: `var result = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<dynamic>; Assert.IsNotNull(result);`

Comment: I tried "var result = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<dynamic>; "
The value of result is null.

Comment: @Jimesh I've revised my solution, please check it.

Comment: Nice efforts but sorry to say- 
Line: dynamic content = ((dynamic)actionResult).Content;

Exception: An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Content'

Comment: Okay, one last attempt :D `var actionResult = ((dynamic)controller).MethodName(); var content = (dynamic)actionResult.Content;`

Comment: The actionResult has Content but still it says " 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Content'".  Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @Jimesh Okay, I'm sorry. I'll delete this post later today.

Comment: Peter you can keep it as it might be helpful for people in one or another way. Example: Assert.AreEqual(resultType.GetGenericTypeDefinition(), typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<>)); works well

Comment: @Jimesh Okay then I've just added a disclaimer there

Comment: @Jimesh Wait a sec, maybe `var` fool us. Rather than declaring the `actionResult` with `var` we might need to declare it as `dynamic` to have a `Content` property on it. `dynamic actionResult = ((dynamic)controller).MethodName(); dynamic content = (dynamic)actionResult.Content;`

Comment: Same issue persists :(